# Can't transfer value from mapping inside mapping

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, mapping, address.transfer

The title of this issue might seem strange because I can't figure out exactly what the problem is.  But here is what is happening:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Escrow {
  address public owner;
  uint public fee;

  //Balances temporarily made public for testing; to be removed
  mapping (address =>  mapping (address => uint)) public balances;

  function Escrow() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  //Fee should be set in PPM
  function setFee(uint price) onlyOwner external {
    fee = price;
  }

  function start(address payee) payable external {
    balances[msg.sender][payee] = balances[msg.sender][payee] + msg.value;
  }

  function end(address payer, address payee) onlyOwner external {
    uint value = balances[payer][payee];
    //uint paidFee = value / (1000000 / fee);
    //uint payment = value - paidFee;
    //payee.transfer(payment);
    //owner.transfer(paidFee);
    //balances[payer][payee] = 0
    payee.transfer(value)
  }
}
```

I've commented out a bunch of lines that I would like to get working in the `end` function, because I can't get even the other parts working.

Steps:

1. Creat contract from first address in testRPC
2. I call start, from the second address in my testRPC, sending 2 ETH,
   to the last address: `start("0xb631fc401038e191fa38c4ff20dcce8d13eb6ebc" , { from "0x1c34d277b51ec49536fe7843e289933e0f8020ed", value: 2000000000000000000000 })`
3. I check: `balances("0x1c34d277b51ec49536fe7843e289933e0f8020ed", "0xb631fc401038e191fa38c4ff20dcce8d13eb6ebc")`, I see `0: uint256: 2000000000000000000` --So far so good.
4. This is where I get into trouble.  If I call `end("0x1c34d277b51ec49536fe7843e289933e0f8020ed", "0xb631fc401038e191fa38c4ff20dcce8d13eb6ebc")`, I get: `transact to Escrow.end errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`

If I change `end` to just return `balances[payer][payee]`, I get 0.

If I change `end` to just transfer 1 ETH to payee, I get a gas error.

So I can't figure out what the source of this issue is.  Can you give any advice?

Comment: Superficially, it appears to work as expected, so I imagine the issue might be outside the code. Can you elaborate on step 1? How exactly do you go about "Creat contract from first address in testRPC"? Are you copying bytecode from Remix, deploying using Remix, compiling/deploying with truffle or something else? There is some ambiguity with `pragma ^0.4.13` and your process. I suspect you've got version incompatibilities to sort out. A suggestion is to remove the `^` and resolve the resulting complaints by bringing things into strong explicit alignment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**end()** method of this contract should be **payable** as there is **transfer** inside the method. And also use **safeMath.sol** of **OpenZeppelin** for any mathematical calculation inside contract. I rewrite the code. Please find:

**safeMath.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

/**
 * @author OpenZeppelin
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}
```

**escrow.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import './safeMath.sol';

contract Escrow {

    using SafeMath for uint;

    address public owner;
    uint public fee;

    mapping (address =>  mapping (address => uint)) public balances;

    function Escrow() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    //Fee should be set in PPM
    function setFee(uint price) onlyOwner external {
        fee = price;
    }

    function start(address payee) payable external {
        balances[msg.sender][payee] = balances[msg.sender][payee] + msg.value;
    }

    function end(address payer, address payee) onlyOwner payable external {
        uint value = balances[payer][payee];
        uint paidFee = value.div(uint(1000000).div(fee));
        uint payment = value.sub(paidFee);
        payee.transfer(payment);
        owner.transfer(paidFee);
        balances[payer][payee] = 0;
        payee.transfer(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted here works fine, except the forgotton `;` at `payee.transfer(value)`.

My guess is that as the error says, you simply didn't provide enough gas.

[image]

Comment: How were you able to set a gas amount in Remix?

Comment: BTW, I'm using Ganache as my test RPC, so the environment is Web3 provider

Comment: Image here: https://res.cloudinary.com/dtvc9q04c/image/upload/v1524527279/Screenshot_from_2018-04-23_19-45-23.png

Comment: Top-right. "Gas limit" and "wei" (which can you change to ether) allow you to "configure" your tx.

Comment: I know that I can raise the gas limit, which I've done.  You are saying that I should also put some eth into the value form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the from account in step 4, like you have in step 2 but without any value. Otherwise it doesn't know what account to charge for gas.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I am doing this from the Remix IDE, so a From value is required, and I've been doing it from the owner.

Comment: It executed for me with the JavaScript VM. Have you tested other environments?

Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Gf0fjqu

Comment: Goodness.  I banged my head on this for so long, and it seems to be an issue with my testRPC.  It works just fine from the Javascript VM.  Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Try googling "ethereum testrpc out of gas". There are several posts with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
function start(address payee) payable external {
    balances[msg.sender][payee] = balances[msg.sender][payee] + msg.value;
  }
```

To call this function ,

```
start("0xb631fc401038e191fa38c4ff20dcce8d13eb6ebc" , { from "0x1c34d277b51ec49536fe7843e289933e0f8020ed", value: 2000000000000000000000 })
```

You passed Value and now your `value` is stored on `balances[msg.sender][payee]` finally after adding.
Lets jump on second function

```
function end(address payer, address payee) onlyOwner external {
    uint value = balances[payer][payee];
     payee.transfer(value);  
  }
```

for the first time you transact this function then all your value is transferred to an address of payee.
for the second time you transact this function then  you have no value left then you get the vm error.

If you have not did this mistake then check web3js. 
please pass  optional parameter.

> end("0x1c34d277b51ec49536fe7843e289933e0f8020ed",
>   "0xb631fc401038e191fa38c4ff20dcce8d13eb6ebc",{from,gasPrice,gas})

```
options - Object (optional): The options used for calling.
        from - String (optional): The address the call “transaction” should be made from.
        gasPrice - String (optional): The gas price in wei to use for this call “transaction”.
        gas - Number (optional): The maximum gas provided for this call “transaction” (gas limit).
```